# $(document.body).height() returns the same value as $(window).height()

Tags: jquery, height

my basic structure was like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="controlBar"></div>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
    <div id="pageHeader">
      <nav><ul><li><li></ul></nav>
    </div>
    <section id="pageContent"></section>
    <footer id="pageFooter"></footer>
</body>
```

where `#controlBar` has a fixed position and `#placeholder` has the same height as `#controlBar`.  The combine height inside the body was about 400px.

I'm trying to get the height of the body using `$(document.body).height()`, but the value returned was the same as `$(window).height()`, which is over 900px. I also tried `$(document).height()`, but still same result.

Comment: Means your `<html>` is the same size as `<body>`

Comment: Can you post a fiddle example. `body` height should be the same as the combined heights of the elements in your document. Do you have a `100%` height specified somewhere?

Comment: What browser are you in?

Comment: i'm using chrome and firefox, both have the same problem, and firefox returns 0 for the body. And i double checked, no 100% height on any element

Comment: i solved my own problem, the problem was that i put the javascript on the top of the page before the html tags and the footer has to set to clear:both in css.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to know the actual size of the `window` you could check it like this:

```
window.innerHeight
```